# Heap-corruption when trying to free memory

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc, heap-corruption

I'm currently learning the Win32 API and trying to reproduce the original Windows Notepad (not every of its aspect, of course!).
I have recreated a function that reads a file to have more controls on what is read.

Basically, this function puts all the characters into a buffer throught a `while` loop which then will be displayed by `ShowWindowText()`
I retrieve the file size at the beginning, but when it comes to add the new '\r' character to the file, I need to realloc sizeof(wchar_t) more bytes to the buffer to avoid an out of range error.

The problem is that when the program opens a file, it crash with a `heap corruption` error and after some test I've found out that it was due to `free()`.

If someone could enlighten me...

```cpp
    int main() {
    FILE* inFile;
    inFile = _wfopen_s(&inFile, L"test.txt", L"r");

    if (inFile != NULL) {
        // Get file size
        fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_END);
        long fileSize = ftell(input_file);
        
        wchar_t* buffer = (wchar_t*)malloc((fileSize + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));

        int position = 0;
        int toRealloc = 0;
        wchar_t currentChar;

        /* Replace every '\n' chars with "\r\n" to support 
           breakline on the EDIT control */
        while (position < fileSize) {
            currentChar = fgetwc(inFile);
            // Maybe the switch is useless here...
            switch (currentChar) {
            case L'\n':
            {
                ++toRealloc;
                wchar_t* newPtr = 
                (wchar_t*)realloc(buffer, (fileSize+toRealloc)*sizeof(wchar_t));

                if (NULL != newPtr) {
                    buffer = newPtr; // Assign the new adress
                    buffer[position] = L'\r';
                    buffer[position + 1] = L'\n';
                    position += 2; // Ignore the second character
                }
                else {
                    // An error has occured and the memory can't be allocated
                    free(buffer);
                    return -1;
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                buffer[position] = currentChar;
                ++position;
                break;
            }
            buffer[fileSize + toRealloc] = L'\0';
            free(buffer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: My new loop to read a file

```cpp
        #define END_PROGRAM return -1;

        setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
        FILE* inFile;
        _wfopen_s(&inFile, app.document.path, L"r");

        if (NULL == inFile) {
            // Error when opening the file
            END_PROGRAM
        }

        // Check if the stream is byte-oriented or wide-oriented.
        int streamResult = fwide(inFile, NULL);
        if (streamResult < 0) {
            fwide(inFile, 1);
        }

        fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

        int toRealloc = 0;
        int position = 0;

        wchar_t* buffer = (wchar_t*)malloc(toRealloc * sizeof(wchar_t));
        wchar_t currChar;

        do {
            // alloc memory for each new character.
            ++toRealloc;
            wchar_t* new_ptr = (wchar_t*)
                realloc(buffer, (toRealloc + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));

            if (NULL == new_ptr) {
                /* An error has occured, free the allocated memory 
                   and close the program. */
                free(buffer);
                END_PROGRAM
            }

            buffer = new_ptr;

            currChar = fgetwc(inFile);

            if (currChar == L'\n') {
                buffer[position] = L'\r';
                ++toRealloc;
                wchar_t* new_ptr = (wchar_t*)realloc(buffer, toRealloc * sizeof(wchar_t));
                if (new_ptr != NULL) {
                    buffer = new_ptr;
                }
                else {
                    free(buffer);
                    END_PROGRAM
                }
                buffer[position + 1] = L'\n';
                position += 2;
            }
            else {
                buffer[position] = currChar;
                ++position;
            }
        } while (currChar != WEOF);

        buffer[position] = L'\0';
        fclose(inFile);

        // Use buffer

        free(buffer);
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. Also include the exact input.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * (fileSize + 1)` - but `fileSize` hasn't been set at this point.

Comment: Why are you reading the first byte of a UTF-16 code unit as if you assumed the file could only contain ASCII characters?

Comment: @500InternalServerError In my original code, `fileSize` is indeed set to the current opened file size value:
`fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);
long file_size = ftell(input_file);`

@AbrahamLe I don't know if it's what you want to meant, but now I read the "selected wide char" with `fgetwc()` but nothing seems to change.
The error occur when it tries to `free()` the buffer.
I think something is wrong with `realloc`, but it succeeds because `newPtr` is not NULL.
When I remove this line (`free(buffer)`), it works but it also cause a memory leak in the program which is very problematic

Comment: `ftell` output is in bytes. You are reading `wchar_t` which are not bytes. `while (position < fileSize) {` is not a good idea in any case. If you want to read an entire file, you should *always* read while `read` (or whatever function you are using) succeeds, and stop as soon as it fails. Do not measure file size to determine your buffer size, just `realloc` as necessary.

Comment: Your `free(buffer)` is too early. It should not be in the loop, or you will throw away all of your data in progress. It's undefined behavior to `realloc` a `free`d pointer.

Comment: Hello! sorry for the late response and merry Christmas!
I managed to make my code working without any error, thank you to all for your responses!
I removed `fileSize` and used the `WEOF` macro to check for the end-of-file special character, therefore I think that there's less risks to have an undefined behaviour.
I will edit my post to show you how does the new loop looks, I'm sure it can be improved.